# Remove char to print the longest string in alphabetical order

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for a solution to print the longest string in alphabetic order from an input string.

*Limitation: we have to take care of the char positions.*

> Example 1:  input: **abdb**, output: **abd**, Explanation: abd is the longest
> string from the input string, if I remove b.
>
> Example 2: input: **xvwzxz**, output: **vwxz**, Explanation: if I remove xz I will
> get the longest string.
> I have to remove 1st and 4th char.

MyCode:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(wordInSeq("xvwzzzxyxx"));
    }

    private static String wordInSeq(String s) {
        
        int max=0; String maxl = "";
        System.out.println(s.length());
        for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1;i++){
            String o = Character.toString(s.charAt(i));
            for(int j=i+1; j<s.length()-1;j++){
                if(s.charAt(i)<s.charAt(j)){
                    if(!o.contains(Character.toString(s.charAt(j))))
                    o=o+Character.toString(s.charAt(j));
                }
                        
            }
            if(max < o.length()){
                max = o.length();
                maxl = o;
            }
            //System.out.println(maxl);
        }
        return maxl;
    }
}
```

above code is passing only a few scenarios as output is not coming in alphabetic order.

If I pass `xvwzxz`, the output is: `vwzx`.  It's taking `Z` at `4th` position whereas it should take `Z` at the last position.

We have to get the exact solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is y your problem? Do you understand why your algorithm does not solve the problem? If no, debug it. If yes try to fix the algorithm / create a new one. For this small problems you can try it with pen and paper. What would a human do to solve the task?

Comment: An additional resource that might help is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect as **@Eran** explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59263447/4964822).

You should instead use dynamic programming to solve this, which is actually [Longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) as pointed by **@SaiBot** in the comments.

So, for a string say **xvwzxz**, we initialize an empty array with values as `1` since we can always get a sequence of length at least `1`.

```
x v w z x z
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Now, let i=0. We move from `i` till `0` for **every** character and compare characters and get the maximum increasing length for each individual character.

**i=0**

```
   x v w z x z
   1 1 1 1 1 1
   ^
```

**i=1**

```
   x v w z x z
   1 1 1 1 1 1
     ^
```

**i=2**

```
   x v w z x z
   1 1 2 1 1 1
       ^
```

Since w > v, w + v = 2(in length)

**i=3**

```
   x v w z x z
   1 1 2 3 1 1
         ^
```

**i=4**

```
   x v w z x z
   1 1 2 3 3 1
           ^
```

**i=5**

```
   x v w z x z
   1 1 2 3 3 4
             ^
```

So, the maximum increasing length for `xvwzxz` is `4`. To construct the answer from these integers, we can just create another array(or a 2D array) and keep a simple previous index from whom we got the maximum answer and climb up that ladder to get the actual longest increasing string .

**Snippet:**

```
   private static String wordInSeq(String s) {
        int[][] dp = new int[s.length()][2];
        int max_index = -1;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i){
            dp[i][0] = 1;
            dp[i][1] = i;
            for(int j=i-1;j>=0;--j){
                if(s.charAt(i) > s.charAt(j)){
                    if(dp[i][0] < 1 + dp[j][0]){
                        dp[i][0] = 1 + dp[j][0];
                        dp[i][1] = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(max_index == -1 || dp[max_index][0] < dp[i][0]) max_index = i;
        }

        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder("");
        int temp = max_index;
        while(dp[temp][1] != temp){
            res.append(s.charAt(temp));
            temp = dp[temp][1];
        }
        res.append(s.charAt(temp));
        return res.reverse().toString();
    }
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/IpIdk7

**Important Note:** It is quite possible that there can be multiple correct answers for a given string. For example,  for `efghabcd`, both `efgh` and `abcd` are correct answers.

Comment: Thanks vivek, your code works but I am getting performance issue with this code

Comment: @HiteshKumar Yes, it's quadratic in nature. What is the possible max length of the string?

Comment: @HiteshKumar You can refer to Kevin's answer and for the approach mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect:

1. In `if (s.charAt(i)<s.charAt(j))` you compare the current character of the outer loop (which will become the first character of the output `String`) with the current character of the inner loop. This means that after adding v, w and z to `o`, you add `x` (since `v` < `x`) and get the invalid output "vwzx". You should compare `s.charAt(j)` to the last character added to `o`.
2. Fixing the first issue will make sure the output `String` is in alphabetic order, but it won't necessarily find the longest possible output. The reason is that you only skip characters of the input `String` if they belong to a prefix of `s` (i.e. all the characters with index < i) or if you already added them to `o`. This means that for the "xvwzxz", you'll build the "vwz" output, and won't be able to find the longer "vwxz" output, since you don't have logic to skip the first 'z'.

Comment: Thank Eran for you analysis on my logic, I am trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a backtracking mechanism because if the input string is "abczde", the longest result is "abcde", not "abcz".

Here is an example of implementation:

```
private static String wordInSeq(String s) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
    wordsInSeq(s, buf, 0, words);
    String longest = "";
    for (String word: words) {
        if (word.length() > longest.length()) {
            longest = word;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}

private static void wordsInSeq(String s, StringBuilder buf, int pos,
        Set<String> words) {
    if (pos >= s.length()) {
        words.add(buf.toString());
    } else {
        int len = buf.length();
        wordsInSeq(s, buf, pos+1, words);
        char cur = s.charAt(pos);
        if (len == 0 || cur > buf.charAt(len-1)) {
            buf.append(s.charAt(pos));
            wordsInSeq(s, buf, pos+1, words);
        }
        buf.setLength(len);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maurice Perry your solution is working and passing all scenarios, Thank you much but it's taking more time due to recursion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For this questions, to be honest, I have not done the Longest increasing subsequence before. I think the Efficient algorithms code at this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)  -(Pointed out by [Saibot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8592647/saibot)) look really good. Thus, I translated that code into Java for you with a twist. That code was modified so that it will work for your cases. You can read more on that Wikipedia page to understand the algorithms.

At first, I thought this question was about getting the character out from a string sorted without repeating character.

As suspected that Wikipedia's method is one of the most efficient methods, I put the code below through a benchmark test. I generated 1,000,000 strings, each with the len of 15, and only contain lower-alpha characters. Below is the result and take note that the result is in milliseconds.

**Benchmark:** https://ideone.com/4ZBwda

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(wordInSeq("xvwzzzxyxx"));
        System.out.println(wordInSeq("abdb"));
        System.out.println(wordInSeq("xvwzxz"));
    }

    private static String wordInSeq(String s) {

        int P[] = new int[s.length()];
        int M[] = new int[s.length()+1];

        int L = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )  {
            // Binary search for the largest positive j ≤ L
            // such that X[M[j]] <= X[i]
            int lo = 1;
            int hi = L;

            while ( lo <= hi ){
                // This is equal to round up for / 2
                int mid = ((lo+hi) >> 1) + ((lo + hi) & 1);

                // This was change
                // <  : low to high no repeat
                // <= : low to high repeating
                // >  : high to low no repead
                // >= : high to low repeating 
                if (s.charAt(M[mid]) < s.charAt(i))
                    lo = mid+1;
                else
                    hi = mid-1;
            }
            // After searching, lo is 1 greater than the
            // length of the longest prefix of X[i]
            int newL = lo;

            // The predecessor of X[i] is the last index of 
            // the subsequence of length newL-1
            P[i] = M[newL-1];
            M[newL] = i;

            if (newL > L){
                // If we found a subsequence longer than any we've
                // found yet, update L
                L = newL;
            }
        }

        // Reconstruct the longest increasing subsequence
        char S[] = new char[L];
        int k = M[L];
        for (int i = L - 1; i > -1; i-- ){
            S[i] = s.charAt(k);
            k = P[k];
        }
        return new String(S);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to sort the characters of the input String and return a String made of all the characters in order without duplicates. That's not what is required. For input String "xzy" you should return "xz" or "xy", not "xyz" - you are allowed to skip characters, but not to change the order of characters.

Comment: @eran - yup that what my code does, and that what the OP asked for. Read the OP example 1 and 2.

Comment: In the given examples, it is possible to include all the unique characters in the output by removing one or two characters while preserving the original order, but in the general case it's not. Note the `Limitation: we have to take care of the char positions.` requirement.

Comment: @eran - nmv I read the comments of the question. The OP didn't really explain the question. I fix this later. Thank you.